# How to render razor view in aurelia custom element?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, aurelia

I am successfully rendering mvc view when it comes to render the normal aurelia class as below:

```
export class App {
  getViewStrategy() {
        return 'app';
    }
}
```

How would I render my razor view when using custom element basic example is I got a nav-bar.html which is getting use to render my menu but instead of nav-bar.html I want to use cshtml page so that I can use some server side code to hide and show few elements. If I just do following

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
     ....
  </nav>
</template>
```

And in corresponding nav-bar.ts

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class NavBar {
    @bindable router;

    constructor() {

        console.info("Ctor");
    }

    bind() {
        console.info("bind");
    }

    getViewStrategy() {
        console.log('get view');
        return 'nav-bar'
    }
}
```

And use it like, in my app.cshtml. One thing to note if I change from="nav-bar" to nav-bar.cshtml and get rid of nav-bar.ts file aurelia expect nav-bar.js all the time as it only care for js and html file

```
<template>
    <require from="nav-bar"></require>
    <require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
    <nav-bar router.bind="router"></nav-bar>
    <div class="page-host">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

In this case my Ctor and bind is logging but get view doesn't which mean i cannot use server side view or is there any way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use the `@useView` decorator.

**navbar.js**

```
import { useView } from 'aurelia-framework';

@useView('navbar.cshtml')
export class NavBarCustomElement {
    // ...
}
```

**app.html**

```
<require from="nav-bar"></require>
<nav-bar></nav-bar>
<div class="page-host">
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Working example here: https://gist.run/?id=8f3b972d4008f07c1a11142b4b5b6e0e

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Just implemented that and it works when u have associated navbar.js file but what if I don't have one and just binding router straight in my cshtml page like <template bindable="router">. Can i get the solution for that.

Comment: I don't really understand. Either edit your question with your example, or open a new question. :) Thank you for accept / upvote!